# Angular 5 httpClient both HttpHeaders and a Response object?

Tags: angular, httpclient

I'm using Angular 5 with httpClient.

This code sends the post with HttpHeaders. Great!

```
const httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
   }),
};


return this.http.post<any>(serviceUrl + url, dto, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

This code returns the response object. Great!

```
  return this.http.post<any>(serviceUrl + url, fileForUpload, { observe: 'response' })
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
```

How can I have both? POST with HttpHeaders AND get the response object? Thanks

Comment: The third parameter to `.post` is an *object*, it can have more than one thing in it... Also note that you should be more specific than `any` for the generic type, otherwise the compiler can't help you at all with the response.

Answer (score -1):

```
const httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
   }),
   observe: "response"
};

return this.http.post<any>(serviceUrl + url, fileForUpload, httpOptions)
.pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

this worked:

```
export interface IRequestOptions {
  body?: any;
  headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | Array<string> };
  observe?: any;
  params?: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | Array<string> };
  reportProgress?: boolean;
  responseType?: "json";
  withCredentials?: boolean;
}

const options: IRequestOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Authorization": "my-auth-token"
}),
observe: "response"
};
```